# C language recursion factorial not working

Tags: c, function, recursion

For the code shown below I get no response; I kept it minimal with no conditions, imagining people will choose positive number for example. It gives me no response besides:

> Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 3.194 s

If I type 5, answer should be 120, not here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int faktorijel(int x) {
    return (x*faktorijel(x-1));
}

main() {
    int a,b;
    printf("Type in a number:");
    scanf("%d\n", &a);
    b=faktorijel(a);
    printf("Result is %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Infinite recursion. Take a closer look as to why that's happening.

Comment: @njuffa I haven't slept from studying c, so I can barely watch at the screen, but my only guess is no down base number. It goes to the infinite negative

Comment: If your loop has no termination condition it will loop forever. Same principle applies with recursion. You must have a stop condition.

Comment: @tadman tnx both, just added for and it fixed itself.

Comment: OT: indent your code.

Comment: Indent your code. It will help you to organize and understand it better, and ease debug. Many editors can help you with that (but none will do it for you completely). 
If you're on / have access to linux can download and use indent or cb command in the command line (look it up).

Answer (score 1):

you should set stop `if`:

```c
int faktorijel(int x){
        if (x == 1) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return (x*faktorijel(x-1));
        }
}
```

Comment: I just added for loop and it worked. Tnx for this as well!

Comment: 1 thing confuses me tho with if here. I read that function will return only 1 thing. Won't this return 1 instead of factorial number i need? Cause eventually x will become ==1

Comment: The basis case here is nonstandard.  It should be testing for `x == 0`, so that it can handle `0!` which is `1`.  It's pretty useless if it doesn't handle that case, since it arises all the time.

Comment: It is true! To control this, the situation must change.

Comment: You don't need an else too (you are returning anyway)